# Does a ground need to be install in a 2' x 4' outside junction box?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, grounding

i have a bunch of outdoors 2' x 4' open bottom concrete junction boxes. the question is, does each box need to have a ground rod installed and bonded to the ground wire? if so can someone please point me in the right direction in the NEC code book?

Answer (score 1):

If these are just junction boxes you don't need a ground rod. Why do you think you need a rod? If a transformer vault or the base of a power pedestal that would be a different answer. Grounding electrodes are covered starting in 250.50.